# Efficient way to create 10 instances of Tor circuit

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, connection

What I am trying to do is create a fast way I can build 10 circuits, the hops will always be the same but I need them to have a new sock connection. (A circuit in Tor is like a unique connection).

My standard code is :

```
circ_to_ip= TorCircuit(ssl_sock)
create_circuits(circ_to_ip, hops_in_circ)
```

This creates a single circuit called `circ_to_ip`, and then I can create a circuit through this, the circ_to_ip` creates a new sock connection?

I tried the code below:

```
n = 1
while n < 10:

    n= TorCircuit(ssl_sock)
    create_circuits(n, hops_in_circ)
    print "circuit",n 
    n = n + 1 
sys.exit(0)
```

However when `n` gets assigned `TorCircuit` it becomes an instance rather than an `int` and therefore fails.

How can I create 10 circuits, my original plan was just to create 10 different names to do this but not only does this not work I also feel there is a better method?

The TorCircuit class is below if it is needed

```
TOR_CIRCID_COUNTER = 1
class TorCircuit():
    def __init__(self, sock):
        global TOR_CIRCID_COUNTER
        self.hops = []
        self.circId = TOR_CIRCID_COUNTER
        TOR_CIRCID_COUNTER+=1
        self.socket = sock
        self.tempX = 0
        self.packetSendCount = 0
        self.cookie = []
```

Thanks:)

Comment: Have you considered a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)?!

Comment: Yes, but is this the most efficient way of doing it,the example is for 10 but the size will varry dynamically

Comment: Yes, that's fine, lists can vary in length

Comment: You might want to consider wrapping the creation code up in a function; then your loop just calls that function 10 times and accumulates the results… at which point it's trivial to turn it into a one-liner list comprehension.

Comment: Also, as a general hint: When you have a problem like "when n gets assignedt TorCircuit it becomes an instance rather than an int and therefore fails", the simplest answer is: "don't do that". Just use a different variable name—`n` for your loop counter int, `circuit` for your `TorCircuit`—and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are currently overwriting your loop counter (`n`) with the new circuit.

What you want to do instead is store these circuits in a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). Also, you may want to use a `for` loop with [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) instead of that `while` loop:

```py
storage = [] # Empty list to store all the circuits
for n in range(10):
    circuit = TorCircuit(ssl_sock)
    create_circuits(circuit, hops_in_circ)
    print "circuit", circuit
    storage.append(circuit) # Add the circuit to the list
```